# How to setup LuisModel for a bot builder sdk bot

Tags: c#, bots, azure-language-understanding

I have created a very basic bot using bot builder 3.15.0.  I have defined and trained LUIS with a couple of intents etc.  I have published as staging.

The result of this is a set of keys.
I have put the first key in as the first parameter to the LuisModelAttribute, the second key as the second parameter and then added domain: westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com and Staging = true

```
[LuisModel("{the first key listed on the LUIS publish page}", "the second key listed on the LUIS publish page",
    domain: "eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com", Staging = true)]
```

I have the following code in my bot's RootDialog

```
        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync (IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;
        await context.Forward(new LuisRepeating(), ResumeAfterLuisDialog, activity, CancellationToken.None);
    }   /* method RootDiaglog MessageReceivedAsync */

    private async Task ResumeAfterLuisDialog (IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
```

When I try to test this using the Bot emulator, the connect to the bot works.  During the first post, a breakpoint on the context.Wait in ResumeAfterLuisDialog reveals that result has "fail" with contents of {";None"} and none of my Luis intents (include None and blank) are invoked.

**UPDATE**

As it turns out the code was "working" with or without the {} around the application id.  The real issue is that the Luis Dialog code in the SDK is throwing a InvalidIntentHandlerException at line 416 of LuisDialog, but the current code on GitHub does the throw on line 452 (this was changed with issue 634).

For future people the ";None" is the 'message' passed to the InvalidIntentHandlerException exception which is a ; delimited string of the intents from the LuisIntent attribute on the failing method.  The method name in the exception is the name of the method to which the bot builder attempted to dispatch.  It choose the correct method etc. so now my jobs are
1) - Figure out why I am not using current code
2) - Why my method declaration is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your LuisModel attribute properties. 
I think you don't need to put App ID in the curly braces. Try removing the curly braces around your "the first key listed on the LUIS publish page".

Also type the below URL in your browser after replacing app ID, subscription key and your phrase and hit enter. If there is any error you will come to know what kind of error, etc.

https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/APPID?subscription-key=subscriptionKey&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q=yourPhraseHere

Comment: Clicking the link (which looks a lot like yours above) on the Luis publish page, results in {"query":null,"intents":[],"entities":[]}
So I guess that means everything on that end is correct.

Comment: @Soho Developer,  just wanted to know for the benefit of other people who read this Q&A later.

Answer (score 0):

As Ranganatha mentioned the curly braces should be removed. It should be in the following format with App Id and subscription key. You can find more code samples [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder).

```
[LuisModel("9fa4985b-xxxxxxx-b726795a98b4", "a5d38xxxxxe3671953")]
```

You can user endpoint [url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-create-app#publish-your-app) to test your app. Based on the [http codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-response-codes), you can debug the error.

If you want to use Authoring API to train and publish the app, you can find more information [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f).
If there are any other issues, please reach out to Luisuservoice@microsoft.com.